# Swift UserDefaults get values from array

Tags: arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have `UserDefaults` array like:

```
let userValue = ["name": self.nameLbl.text ?? "", "lastName": self.lastNameLbl.text ?? "", "city": cityLbl.text ?? ""] as! [String : String]
var userArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "userInfo") as? [[String: String]] ?? []
userArray.append(userValue)
UserDefaults.standard.set(userArray, forKey: "userInfo")
```

How can I get key values example to print type

`[["name": .., "lastName":..,],["name": .., "lastName":..,],["name": .., "lastName":..,]...]`

If I print like this :

```
if let array = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "userInfo") as? [[String: String]] {
    for dictionary in array {
        print(dictionary["name"])
        print(dictionary["lastName"])
        print(dictionary["city"])
    }
}
```

in console get :

`Lars 
James 
Ulrich 
Hetfield 
Gentofte 
California`

I want it like this : `[[ Lars, Ulrich,Gentofte],[James, Hetfield, California]]`

Comment: This is really confusing. You seem to want an array of dictionaries but `userValue` is just a single dictionary. `userValue` isn't being used in your code. Why do you get an array for user defaults and immediately set the same key with the obtained value? Then you ask about printing something. What are you printing? What do you get now versus the format you actually want? Please [edit] your question (do not post comments) to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add  `key-value` pair in the array and then print array. You will get your expected answer

```
let userValue = ["name": self.nameLbl.text ?? "", "lastName": self.lastNameLbl.text ?? "", "city": cityLbl.text ?? ""] as! [String : String]
        var userArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "userInfo") as? [[String: String]] ?? []

        // Appending the different -2 userValue to userArray
        userArray.append(userValue)
        userArray.append(userValue)

        UserDefaults.standard.set(userArray, forKey: "userInfo")

        if let array = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "userInfo") as? [[String: String]] {

       var dataValues = Array<Any>()
       array.forEach { (object) in
       dataValues.append(Array(object.values))
      }
    print(dataValues)

 }
```

**Here you can check demo:**

```
let userValue = ["name": "j", "lastName":  "o", "city":  "g"] as! [String : String]

// Appending the different -2 userValue to userArray
var a = [userValue, userValue, userValue]

var b = Array<Any>()
a.forEach { (object) in
    b.append(Array(object.values))
}
print(b)
```

Comment: Here is the full demo as you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

To add an `key-value` pair to existing array, you just to need to append `userValue` to your array. Like:

```
    let userValue = ["name": self.nameLbl.text ?? "", "lastName": self.lastNameLbl.text ?? "", "city": cityLbl.text ?? ""] as! [String : String]
    var userArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "userInfo") as? [[String: String]] ?? []

    // Append the userValue to userArray
    userArray.append(userValue)

    UserDefaults.standard.set(userArray, forKey: "userInfo")
```

To fetch the `dictionary` from the array you can use

```
    if let array = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "userInfo") as? [[String: String]] {
        for dictionary in array {
            print(dictionary["name"])
            print(dictionary["lastName"])
            print(dictionary["city"])
        }
    }
```