# Swift Alamofire put value to string

Tags: arrays, swift, string, request, alamofire

I can't solve the problem in putting value to parameters request in `Alamofire`

Im need to put data like :

```
[["code": 40, "counts": 10], ["code": 43, "counts": 5], ..]
```

Im trying :

```
let jsonObject = [["code": 40, "counts": 10], ["code": 43, "counts": 5]]
let json = JSON(jsonObject)
let jsonString = json.rawString(.utf8)!

 let params = [.."others parameters":.., "order" : jsonString] as [String : Any]

Alamofire.request("http://...", method: .get, parameters: params).responseJSON { response in
```

And It's works great

But this array Im need to put from `UserDefaults` and Im trying to do it like so:

```
var ordString = ""

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
 if let userArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "products") as? [[String : String]] {
var text = "["
for user in userArray {

let quantNumber = user["quantityProd"] ?? ""
let codeNumber = user["codeProd"] ?? ""

 text.append("""
            ["code": \(codeNumber), "counts": \(quantNumber)],
             """)
}
text.removeLast(1)
text.append("]")
print(text) . // Give me [["code": 40, "counts": 10], ["code": 43, "counts": 5]]

ordString = text
```

And in `Alamofire` :

```
let jsonObject = ordString
let json = JSON(jsonObject)
let jsonString = json.rawString(.utf8)!
```

And when make request give me error `JSON INPUT ERROR`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating string instead of `Array` of `key-value pair`:

```
    var arrayOfData = Array<Any>()
    if let userArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "products") as? [[String : String]] {

        for user in userArray {

            let dict = ["code": user["quantityProd"] ?? "","counts": user["codeProd"] ?? ""]
            arrayOfData.append(dict)
        }
    }

    let json = JSON(arrayOfData)
    let jsonString = json.rawString(.utf8)!

    let params = [.."others parameters":.., "order" : jsonString] as [String : Any]
```

I have also updated you on your last question that you are doing wrong and also give you a example(demo) in my answer. Please have a look: [Swift UserDefaults get values from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50193212/swift-userdefaults-get-values-from-array/50193567#50193567)